# How to show a method which return string array in uml?

Tags: java, uml

how to show a method which return string array in uml
method looks like this

```
public String[] delete(int col, int row){}
```

Is this representation correct?

```
+delete(col: int; row: int): String[]
```

Answer (score 3):

Your notation is missing a number [2], range [0..45] or asterisk [*] within the brackets. An array (or any other collection) can be expressed as cardinality in UML2. See cardinality of Property in OMG UML 2 superstructure.

Comment: I couldn't understand what you are talking about. Is my UML notation wrong? Many people commented as that's correct.

Comment: Your syntax is nearly valid. It only misses the number, range or asterisk (and some nitpicking: the semicolon needs to be a comma). Additionally it does not necessarily mean "array" but just "more than one" (which is ok).

Answer (score 1):

Yes your notation is correct.

```
+delete(col: int; row: int): String[]
```

To get more information you can visit http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_diagram and verify.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that should be understandable - even by code generators.

I find [this site](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/class-diagrams.html) helpful for class diagrams.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you should use multiplicity and also comma to separate arguments

```
+delete(col: int, row: int): String[0..*]
```

In this case, will return a String array with zero or more elements